# Why isn't my Number Guessing loop not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm totally new at Javascript. I just learned about the WHILE loop and I'm trying to create a simple number guessing game, but it doesn't seem to be working. The program is supposed to work like this: The player has 3 tries to guess the random number from 1-5. If guessed wrong, an alert gives a hint whether or not the number is higher or lower. If guessed right, the program congratulates the player and exits the loop. The condition "  ( guessCounter < 3 || +guess !== randomNumber )  " doesn't seem to be working though. Perhaps it's something else. Any help understanding why it's not working is appreciated. Thanks.

```
// Generate random number
const randomNumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * 5 ) + 1;

//  Ask user for guess
let guess = prompt( "Guess a number between 1-5." );

//  Create guessCounter
let guessCounter = 1;

// Allow only 3 guesses. Each wrong guess will hint if the random number is higher or lower. If guessed correctly, congratulate player and exit loop. 


while ( guessCounter < 3 || +guess !== randomNumber ) {
    if ( +guess < randomNumber ) {
        alert(`You did not guess correctly. The number is higher.`);
        guessCounter+= 1;
        guess = prompt("Try again.");
    } else if ( +guess > randomNumber ) {
        alert(`You did not guess correctly. The number is lower.`);
        guessCounter+= 1;
        guess = prompt("Try again.");
    } else {
        alert(`You guessed the correct number. Congrats.`);
    }
};
```

Comment: Replace `||` with `&&` you want your loop to exit when: number of tries exceeded or the user guessed the correct number.

Comment: Also you should move `alert(`You guessed the correct number. Congrats.`);` outside of the loop. You can achieve this by setting a flag when the user has entered the correct number (and `alert()` if the flag is set)

Comment: Remove the `+` on `+guess` because you are already adding 1 to `randomNumber`

Comment: @GetSet `+guess` converts the input to a number that's all.

Comment: Ahh I see. And with that `||` in there, an infinite loop can occur.

Comment: Yes that's what I mentioned earlier. OP needs to change the condition or use logical AND.

Comment: @marco-a Thanks for your input. I'm a bit confused. If I use the && operator...wouldn't both conditions need to be met in order to exit the loop as opposed to "either one or the other"? I initially figured the condition should be stating, "while the guessCounter is less than 3 OR +guess is not equal to randomNumber, keep looping". Ultimately one condition will be met after 3 tries. My apologies if my question is amateurish.

Comment: @webmonkey714 That's the thing `Ultimately one condition will be met after 3 tries` using OR logic is the wrong choice because in an OR condition only one condition needs to be met in order for the whole expression to be true. So even if the user exceeded 3 tries if the guess isn't correct the loop will continue.

Comment: Think about what conditions need to be met in order for the loop to continue: first the user shouldn't have exceeded 3 tries AND not guessed the number correctly. Why ask the user again if he has guessed the number correctly?

Comment: If `guessCounter < 3` yields `false` (which it does after 3 attempts) the loop still can continue because `+guess !== randomNumber` still can evaluate to true. `false || true` is always `true`.

Comment: Note that in my first comment I said `you want your loop to exit when: number of tries exceeded or the user guessed the correct number. ` emphasis on `to exit`. In case you're confused about the `or` in that sentence.

Comment: And there are *always* multiple ways of achieving the same thing in programming. Keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let's see how we can debug this code.

First we need to get rid of any randomness because debugging is much easier when dealing with predictable or constant values:

```
// Generate random number
const randomNumber = 4;
```

Ok so we know the correct random number in our debugging session will always be 4.

Let's enter the correct number in the first run:

Observed behaviour:

- Enter number: 4
- `You guessed the correct number. Congrats.`
- Enter number: 4 (again)
- `You guessed the correct number. Congrats.`

Yikes, this looks like an infinite loop. Why is that?

Let's have a closer look at the expression that ultimately decides whether the loop continues or not:

```
while ( guessCounter < 3 || +guess !== randomNumber ) {
```

We can evaluate those conditions by hand because we know:

1.) `guessCounter` is initialized to `1` and

2.) `guess` is `"4"`, meaning `+guess` is `4` and `randomNumber` is fixed at `4`.

Next we fill in the values:

```
while ( 1 < 3 || 4 !== 4 ) {
```

`1 < 3` gives us `true` and `4 !== 4` also gives us true hence we have:

```
while ( true || true ) {
```

Repeating the same for the second "attempt":

1.) `guessCounter` is `2`

2.) `guess` is `"4"`, meaning `+guess` is `4` and `randomNumber` is fixed at `4`.

Gives us:

```
while ( 2 < 3 || 4 !== 4 ) {
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
while ( true || true ) {
```

So we can already point out that the logic is not working according to our expectations.

We know that the loop should not continue yet it does.¹

I hope this gives you a starting point on how to debug and fix your code.

¹ If you're wondering if you can "break" out a running loop, yes you can: see [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) for that.

Comment: Ah...gotcha. I see now. It actually comes down to not fully understanding the logical AND and OR operations on my part. Thank you for your explanation. Its clear now why the loop is broken. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Generate random number
const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

//  Ask user for guess
let guess = prompt("Guess a number between 1-5.");

//  Create guessCounter
let guessCounter = 1;

// Allow only 3 guesses. Each wrong guess will hint if the random number is higher or lower. If guessed correctly, congratulate player and exit loop.

while (guessCounter < 3) {
  if (guess < randomNumber) {
    alert(`You did not guess correctly. The number is higher.`);
    ++guessCounter;
    guess = prompt("Try again.");
  } else if (guess > randomNumber) {
    alert(`You did not guess correctly. The number is lower.`);
    ++guessCounter;
    guess = prompt("Try again.");
  } else {
    guessCounter = 3;
  }
}

if (+guess === randomNumber) alert(`You guessed the correct number. Congrats.`);
else alert(`You did not guess the correct number.`);
```